# UIWebView not display any content

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I used `UIWebView` with my app I set the default like the next code:-

```
WebViewViewController.h

@interface WebViewViewController :UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
@end

WebViewViewController.m



NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"facebook.com"];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

web view appear but with no data.

Comment: have you set the delegate from storyboard or xib of WebView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`facebook.com` is not valid URL.

It needs to be `http://facebook.com`.

Be sure you set the web view's delegate and implement the delegate methods such as `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`. Then you can see what errors you are getting when a page fails to load.

Answer (score 1):

Replace only URL and check the connection and delegate.

Remove Your .m file code and put my code.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Why does the OP need to remove their .m code and use yours? The only change you made was to update the URL which I mentioned a while ago. There's no reason to post a new answer that doesn't add anything to existing answers.

Comment: i mention the your connection and delegate. is it not working.